# Can not install Omnetpp to M1 Big Surr

Tags: macos, qt5, omnet++, configure, apple-m1

I can not install OMNET++ to my m1 Mac because `configure` script can't install qt libraries.

I get this classic error:

```
configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.
```

Normally OMNET++ comes with its own QT5 libs bundled with it but for some reason it can not detect these libraries.

So I tried:

- Using `brew install qt` and adding it to path
- Manually downloading qt5 and adding it to path
- `source setenv` from zsh then `./configure`
- `. setenv` from bash then `./configure`

These didn't work so, I inspected `config.log` for further details. Which showed

```
ld: library not found for -lQt5Gui
```

Then I changed the line with code in `configure` script, which in at line 4721

```
QT_LIBS=${QT_LIBS:-"-lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL $LDFLAG_LIBPATH$QT_INSTALL_LIBS -Wl,-rpath=$QT_INSTALL_LIBS"}
```

To this, by only changing the first lib.

```
QT_LIBS=${QT_LIBS:-"-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/5.15.2/lib -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL $LDFLAG_LIBPATH$QT_INSTALL_LIBS -Wl,-rpath=$QT_INSTALL_LIBS"}
```

Then it gave similar errors for `Qt5Core` `Qt5Widgets` `Qt5PrintSupport` `Qt5OpenGL` so I removed them and added frameworks folder. Finally I achieved this:

```
QT_LIBS=${QT_LIBS:-"-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/5.15.2/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/5.15.2/Frameworks $LDFLAG_LIBPATH$QT_INSTALL_LIBS -Wl, -rpath=$QT_INSTALL_LIBS"}
```

Still gives me the same error. I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, you should run omnet in x86 emulation mode. Start a shell window with:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
```

And then configure and build OMNeT++ from there. You must run EVERYTHING from that shell.

Comment: Thank you, for now this enabled me to run ```make```